# Why was this migration blocked?

Tags: discussion, migration

This question was migrated from Movies:SE to our site. It appears perfectly on-topic.

[Can anybody identify these Marvel characters?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262394/can-anybody-identify-these-marvel-characters)

It was subsequently answered and was seemingly on its way to attracting other higher quality answers.

The migration was then rejected (due to a binding moderator vote due to it "needing details or clarity" despite the question being perfectly clear) which has resulted in it being pushed back to Movies:SE where it will get deleted.

Why was this migrated question accepted and then subsequently rejected?

Comment: We don't accept migrations, they get pushed to us. The migration was rejected automatically due to the closure. I've not really looked at the question to see if the closure is warranted or not though.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - It seems like a perfectly acceptable question to me. It could certainly have been improved with more details, but it didn't need them to be an acceptable question.

Comment: My bad let me see if I can fix it. *Grumbles* rassa frasssing migrated... Frasssing ....

Comment: For identify-this questions, do the characters need to be demonstrably from the same game/movie/book/franchise/etc? I am wondering where the line would be drawn for being too broad. If one of the sprites in the linked Q was from a DC game would it still be acceptable?

Comment: @fez doesn't matter here, we can't close it without unmigrating it. But I think we should make sure the question is focused and we know where the images are from before plowing ahead

Comment: @fez - possibly that's worthy of its own question but I would say that this is such an 'edge case' that you would be better asking about the specific question rather than trying to make it a policy question (unless you can think of more examples to put into the question)

Comment: @fez: As per the general guidance for Too Broad avoiding multiple questions, I would say that there at least has to be a sincere belief they're from a common source. Posting a bunch of toy images with text of "My Uncle Jimmy always told me these came from a space show he watched" is different from posting a bunch of toy images with the text of "Can anyone identify these toys in this shipment I got from Amazon on remaindered items?" since there's no expectation of a single correct answer.